# Adding control to a panel at runtime

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'd like to add a control A (that exists on a page) to a Footer user control's panel. If I create the control A dynamically and add it, I don't have issues. But I would like to avoid adding this dynamically.

So, I defined control A in the aspx page and in the code behind, I got reference to the footer's panel and did a `Controls.Add()` It works fine, but postbacks from this control has strange behavior (could be due to viewstate?) as it doesn't execute some code that is on the page with a !`IsPostback` condition

Has anyone got something like this working?

Comment: What is the reason you want to avoid doing it dynamically ?
You might want to remove the control from collection and then add it to panel.

Comment: Would like to avoid adding dynamically as it messes up with the control tree. In other words, I need to dynamically create on OnInit which opens up other issues beyond this issue. I did try to remove the control from the collection, but it doesn't seem to be working. I assume you are talking about Page collection? Can you share the code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have some inherit issues with doing this, as the same control existing twice could be a problem.  However, if you are "moving things around", you want to be sure that the control is in the same place on Page_Init() rather than load.